# Problem in line chart plotting with core plot

Tags: ios, graph, charts, core-plot, linechart

I have y axis with numbers of total test
and x axis for time

The following is the code I am using to plot:

```
- (NSUInteger)numberOfRecordsForPlot:(CPPlot *)plot {  
    NSUInteger recordplot;  

    if (plot.identifier == @"Plot Error")  
    {  
        recordplot = [HourErroroArray count];  

        recordplot--;  
    }  

    return recordplot;  
}  


- (NSNumber *)numberForPlot:(CPPlot *)plot field:(NSUInteger)fieldEnum recordIndex:(NSUInteger)index {  
    NSDecimalNumber *num = nil;  
    int eTemp1;  
    int eHour1;  
    int eMin1;  
    int eSec1;  
// Number of the X axis asked  
    if (fieldEnum == CPScatterPlotFieldX)  
    {  

    if (plot.identifier == @"Plot Error")  
        {  
        eHour1=[[HourErroroArray objectAtIndex:index]intValue ];  
        eMin1=[[MinErrorArray objectAtIndex:index]intValue ];  
        eSec1=[[SecErrorArray objectAtIndex:index]intValue ];  

        eTemp1=eHour1*eMin1*eSec1;  

        num = (NSDecimalNumber *)[NSDecimalNumber numberWithInt:eTemp1];  
        }  
    }  
// Number of the Y axis asked  
    else if (fieldEnum == CPScatterPlotFieldY)  
     {   
        if (plot.identifier == @"Plot Error")  
        {  
          num = (NSDecimalNumber *)[NSNumber numberWithInteger:index];  

        }  

     }   

    return num;  

}
```

I can see the graph is plotting but only in a straight line i.e. parallel to xaxis

!->y-axis, _ ->x-axis and . ->line is plotting for values

```
y-axis  
!  
!   
! ...........  
!
______________ x-axis
```

but I want something like the following:

http://www.buggyprogrammer.co.uk/2010/10/03/using-core-plot-to-draw-line-graphs/

Maybe not up-and down lines, but at least with some angle.

Answer (score 0):

You may have switched the x and y values. Did you mean for the y value to be the index and the x value be the calculated value?

Otherwise, insert some NSLog statements in `-numberForPlot:field:recordIndex:` and make sure the numbers (eTemp1, eHour1, eMin1, eSec1) are what you expect.

**[added in response to the comments]**

Check your plot ranges on the plot space to make sure they're reasonable for your data. If the length of the y range is too large, it will compress the plot so it looks like a horizontal line. A common mistake with plot ranges is mistaking the length for the end value when creating the range. CPTPlotRange works the same way as NSRange. As an experiment, try using the plot space method `-scaleToFitPlots:` to have your data fill the plot range. See the Mac CPTTestApp for an example.

Comment: Ya you are right x-axis will contains calculated and y-axis will contains index,as index increase line should be drawn but this not happening, also at debugging time i check x-axis value and its fine....but still i dont know how to figure out this issue

Comment: How many data points are being plotted? Also, check your plot ranges on the plot space to make sure they're reasonable for your data. If the length of the y range is too large, it will compress the plot so it looks like a horizontal line.

Comment: you are right Eric, if i reduce y-axis values then instead of horizontal line i can see few zic-zac lines, but still this is not correct one what i need... do u think have to x-axis also, i am calculating x-axis as follows  : x-axis contains seconds (Hours*Minute*Seconds)

Comment: also i tried xaxis with Hour*Min and then it give min zic-zac with improved one but still it is not curved or angel line in increasing with x an y-axis

Comment: A common mistake with plot ranges is mistaking the `length` for the end value when creating the range. CPTPlotRange works the same way as NSRange. Make sure your plot ranges are correct. As an experiment, try using the plot space method `-scaleToFitPlots:` to have your data fill the plot range. See the Mac CPTTestApp for an example.

Comment: @Eric, thank you very much, you are right problem with ranges, now i can see something better than horizontal line, also can you add range things in ur answer so i can accept  it, may be its useful for others also, thank you very much once again